# postgres-rust error 42601 (Common Syntax Error): Issuing variable table names properly?

Tags: postgresql, rust

## Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
rocket = "0.4.4"
rocket_cors = "0.5.2"
postgres = "0.15.2"
r2d2_postgres = "0.14.0"
r2d2 = "0.8.0"
rocket_contrib = "0.4.4"
serde_json = "1.0.53"
```

I'm attempting to issue variable table names in rust-postgres by using the format! macro so that rust can handle the concatenation itself. `state.val.get().unwrap().execute()` is equivalent to `connection.execute()` in a regular usecase when equal to `postgres::PostgresConnectionManager::new()`. Here's the snippet:

```
let data_u8: &[u8] = data.peek();
let data_str: &str = str::from_utf8(&data_u8).unwrap();
let data_json: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(&data_str).unwrap();

let table_name = data_json["broadcast_category"].to_string().replace(&['\"'][..], "");

let table_create = format!("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category_{} (
            message         VARCHAR NOT NULL,
            name            VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                                                                   )", table_name);
let table_create_ref: &str = &table_create[..];

println!("Table Create fn: {}", table_create);

state.val.get().unwrap().execute(table_create_ref, &[]).unwrap();
```

I only recieve the following error on compile-time: (`data_json["broadcast_category"]` is part of a `serde_json::Value` wrapper recieved on a POST request from the user.

### Error:

> `` thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error(Db(DbError { severity: "ERROR", parsed_severity: Some(Error), code: SqlState("42601"), message: "syntax error at or near \"$1\"", detail: None, hint: None, position: Some(Normal(59)), where_: None, schema: None, table: None, column: None, datatype: None, constraint: None, file: Some("scan.l"), line: Some(1133), routine: Some("scanner_yyerror") }))', src\main.rs:60:9 ``

** src\main.rs:60:9 = `state.val.get().unwrap().execute(table_create_ref, &[]).unwrap();`

As always, your kind efforts and support is appreciated, and we thank you for your involvement in the community.

Comment: Did you try and print out the string value of the query? Looking at the error, you could be using a Postgres placeholder `$1` between quotes, which is incorrect. What's the intention behind the `replace` for `table_name`? Remove all quotes?

Comment: Yes, the query contained quotes from JSON data that I needed to get rid of. If the `broadcast_category` tag was `science`, the table name would be `category_"science"` which doesn't work in Postgres.